# WCF Data Services 5.6.0 and business logic

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

My model generates POCO classes that are then exposed by the service to the client. These classes are partial. So I created another partial class with the same name as the POCO classes and, to test if this solution works, added:

```
public void Validate() {}
```

However, the client just sees the generated POCO classes and therefore my Validate() function is not available.

Is this feature by design when using WCF Data Services & EF6 or am I missing something?

Comment: double check the namespaces too.

Comment: Namespaces match. It looks like it's not possible to expose custom methods in this way.

Comment: I suppose the Dataservice logic looks inside the EDM and does not use Reflection. In that case, yes, forget it.

Comment: Check if the class name are exactly the same

Comment: It is the same because the method can be accessed within the server but not by the client.

Comment: [Contract] attributes in place ?